# My SQL Code is showing 00 instead of 12 AM. How can i adjust this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have the following code which is working great for me.  I am using it in a SSIS package in SQL.  The issue i am having is that between midnight and 1:00 AM, the hour is showing up as 00.  I would like to stay with the following code as much as possible, as it is working for me, but just make the needed adjustement.  Any help would be greatly apprecieated!!!

Thank you,
John

```
    SELECT     CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, DateTimeField) < 13 THEN 
    RIGHT(REPLICATE(' ', 2) + CAST(datepart(hour, DateTimeField) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
    ELSE 
    RIGHT(REPLICATE(' ', 2) + CAST(datepart(hour, dateadd(hour, - 12, DateTimeField))
    AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could simply do this instead:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(14), DateTimeField, 100), 13, 2)
```

Comment: Okay i will give this a try!  So this code will replace all the code i am currently using?  I will let you know very shortly how it turns out.  Thank you!

Comment: @John: Yes. This code should replace all of the code you posted in your question.

Comment: Also keep in mind that since this is part of some larger bit of code (or so it appears) you might be able to replace the whole lot with better use of the `CONVERT` function.

Comment: Good point!  I will be able to test this in a moment.  It sure is a lot cleaner than the way i was doing it, and yes, that was just part of a larger code.  Thank you!

Comment: This worked perfect!  Thank you!  I do not quite understand this coding completely, but i will do some do some more looking into it, for future needs like this.  I appreciate it!

Comment: @John [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with style 100 produces `mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)`. By converting to CHAR(14), I end up with just the first 14 characters `mon dd yyyy hh`. Then the SUBSTRING function pulls out just the `hh` portion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Oracle, since you did not specify.  The general technique is to use the function `TO_CHAR` and a date conversion template that allows 01-12 instead of 00-23.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'HH:MI:SS AM') from dual;

select to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```